# In PHPUnit what is the purpose of the parameter $maxDepth in assertEquals() function

Tags: php, phpunit

I just started to use PHPUnit, and I'm confused as to what the purpose of the `$maxDepth` variable in the `PHPUnit_Framework_Assert` class is for?

> PHPUnit_Framework_Assert

```
public static function assertEquals($expected, $actual, $message = '', $delta = 0.0, $maxDepth = 10, $canonicalize = false, $ignoreCase = false)
{
    $constraint = new PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsEqual(
        $expected,
        $delta,
        $maxDepth,
        $canonicalize,
        $ignoreCase
    );

    self::assertThat($actual, $constraint, $message);
}
```

I've search all the code and it's not documented anywhere, and it also seems that while it sets the variable it's not used at all. Perhaps I'm missing something, can someone provide some insight on this?

Comment: this function has nothing to do with searching through directories so that would be unlikely.

Comment: @nomistic he's talking about in phpunit, not with the UNIX `find` command.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely certain, but I believe that if you're asserting that two complexe, multi-dimensional objects or arrays should be equal, the `$maxDepth` acts as a way to prevent the assertion from going multiple dimensions into the equality. If `$maxDepth = 2` then `$somePopulatedArray[0][4][5][4] = 10` and `$someOtherPopulatedArray[0][4][5][4] = 30` would still pass. In the event that you only need to check, for instance, that the two arrays are of the same size or contain the same top-level values.

Comment: that's possible, but doesn't seem practical as it would be an extreme corner case covering something like that.

Comment: @SebastianBergmann can you show me where in the documentation it's documented, or is this an undocumented feature?

Comment: Looks like it's not documented. Please open a ticket at https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-documentation/issues/new Thanks!

Comment: perfect thanks, I've logged the issue as per your request. https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-documentation/issues/303